# Preserve type when getting nested property via a helper function

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a helper function to extract properties from an object `card` of `Card` type, in typescript.

`(card: Card, key: string) => data`

- a `card` must have either properties `card_faces: {name: string; age: number}[]` or `name: string; age: number`
- If `card.card_faces[0]` exists and key is in `card.card_faces[0]` i.e. key is not `id` in this case, get given property from `card.card_faces[0]`
- Otherwise get given property from `card`

While this function has no problem getting the values, the types aren't preserved, and I spent some time figuring out how to preserve the types. May I know how?

```
interface CardFace {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface Card {
  id: string;
  name?: string;
  age?: number;
  card_faces?: CardFace[];
}

const getPropertyByKey = <K extends keyof Card>(card: Card, key: K) => {
  if (card.card_faces?.[0] && key in card.card_faces[0])
    return card.card_faces[0][key as keyof CardFace]; //I believe "as" here erased type information
  return card[key];
};

const card1 = {
  id: "1",
  name: "Thomas",
  age: 32,
};

const card2 = {
  id: "2",
  card_faces: [
    { name: "Ario", age: 15 },
    { name: "Ario Evolved", age: 27 },
  ],
};

const card1age = getPropertyByKey(card1, "age"); //card1age: string | number | undefined
const card2name = getPropertyByKey(card2, "name"); //card2name: string | number | undefined
const card2id = getPropertyByKey(card2, "id"); //card2name: string | number
console.log(card1age, card2name, card2id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to rewrite this function:

```js
const getPropertyByKey = <K extends keyof Card>(card: Card, key: K) => {
  if (card.card_faces?.[0] && key in card.card_faces[0])
    return card.card_faces[0][key as keyof CardFace]; //I believe "as" here erased type information
  return card[key];
};
```

If you want to infer return type and validate arguments, you should infer your arguments and not just use expected type like you did with `card: Card`

I would rewrite it as follow:

```js
const getProperty = <CardArgument extends Card>(card: CardArgument)=>{}
```

Regarding `key` argument. It should extends a key from provided card and not from base `Card` type. Hence, it should look like this:

```js
const getProperty = <
  CardArgument extends Card,
  Key extends keyof CardArgument
>(card: CardArgument, key: Key) => { }

getProperty(card1, 'card_faces') // should be an error
```

Now, you are not allowed to use `card_faces` property with `card1` even if `card_faces` exists on `Card`.

First of all, lets implement a type which will compute all allowed values which can be used in second argument.
As per my understanding, if card contain `card_faces` property, second argument can be any property of first card in the array or any property of root card except `card_faces` itself. Let's do it:

```js
type GetAllowedProps<T extends Card> =
/**
 * Check whether provided card has card_faces proeprty
 */
  (T extends { card_faces: CardFace[] }
    /**
     * If it has, get all properties from first element in the array an union them with all properties
     * of propvided card except card_faces
     */
    ? Exclude<keyof T['card_faces'][0] | keyof T, 'card_faces'>
    : keyof T)
```

Lets check how it works:

```js
interface CardFace {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface Card {
  id: string;
  name?: string;
  age?: number;
  card_faces?: CardFace[];
}

const card1 = {
  id: "1",
  name: "Thomas",
  age: 32,
};

const card2 = {
  id: "2",
  card_faces: [
    { name: "Ario", age: 15 },
    { name: "Ario Evolved", age: 27 },
  ],
};



type GetAllowedProps<T extends Card> =
  /**
   * Check whether provided card has card_faces proeprty
   */
  (T extends { card_faces: CardFace[] }
    /**
     * If it has, get all properties from first element in the array an union them with all properties
     * of propvided card except card_faces
     */
    ? Exclude<keyof T['card_faces'][0] | keyof T, 'card_faces'>
    : keyof T)

function getProperty<
  CardArgument extends Card,
  Key extends GetAllowedProps<CardArgument>
>(card: CardArgument, key: Key) {
  if (card.card_faces?.[0] && key in card.card_faces[0])
    return card.card_faces[0][key]; // error
  return card[key];
}

getProperty(card2, 'id') // ok
getProperty(card2, 'age') // ok
getProperty(card2, 'name') // ok
getProperty(card2, 'card_faces') // expected error
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NVOo7m)

It validates, however, return type is not infered and we still have an error in inner implementation. Lets infer return type. In order to do that we need to overload our function:

```js
interface CardFace {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}



interface Card {
  id: string;
  name?: string;
  age?: number;
  card_faces?: CardFace[];
}

const card1 = {
  id: "1",
  name: "Thomas",
  age: 32,
};

const card2 = {
  id: "2",
  card_faces: [
    { name: "Ario", age: 15 },
    { name: "Ario Evolved", age: 27 },
  ],
};

type GetAllowedProps<T extends Card> =
  (T extends { card_faces: CardFace[] }
    ? Exclude<keyof T['card_faces'][0] | keyof T, 'card_faces'>
    : keyof T)

const hasProperty = <Obj, Prop extends string>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop)
  : obj is Obj & Record<Prop, unknown> =>
  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);


function getProperty<
  CardArgument extends Card & { card_faces: CardFace[] },
  Key extends keyof CardArgument['card_faces'][0]
>(card: CardArgument, key: Key): CardArgument['card_faces'][0][Key]

function getProperty<
  CardArgument extends Card & { card_faces: CardFace[] } | Card,
  Key extends Exclude<keyof CardArgument, 'card_faces'>
>(card: CardArgument, key: Key): CardArgument[Key]

function getProperty<
  CardArgument extends Card,
  Key extends GetAllowedProps<CardArgument>
>(card: Card, key: Key) {
  const { card_faces } = card
  if (Array.isArray(card_faces)) {
    if (card_faces[0]) {
      if (hasProperty(card_faces[0], key)) {
        return card_faces[0][key]
      }
    }
  }
  return card[key];
}

{
  const id = getProperty(card2, 'id') // string
  const age = getProperty(card2, 'age') // number
  const name_ = getProperty(card2, 'name') // string

  const error = getProperty(card2, 'card_faces') // expected error
}

{
  const id = getProperty(card1, 'id') // string
  const age = getProperty(card2, 'age') // number
  const name_ = getProperty(card2, 'name') // string
  getProperty(card1, 'card_faces') // expected error
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WoMj8N)

In order to fix an error `key can not be used as an index ...` you need to assure TS that `key` exists on this object, this is why I have used `hasProperty`.
You can learn nor about function argument inference from my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

Hope it meets your expectations